# How to convert a column into rows by using split function in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have multiple rows in the Emp Table,
How to convert semicollan separated values into rows SQL,(need to convert all the Department colunm data from all rows and need to get only distinct (unique) values.
Excepted output is:-
HR
Sales
Markting

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)